# Positioning element outside viewport, then pushing it in

Tags: jquery, viewport

**What I want:**

When the page loads, the element should be invisible, no matter how big the size of the viewport is. After a certain amount of time, I want the element to fly in.

**What I have so far:**
This code (http://jsfiddle.net/LdfZw/1/):

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

jQuery

```
var  tenPercent = $( window ).width()*0.1;

$('#div1').css('margin-left',-tenPercent);

setTimeout(function() {
    $ ('#div1').animate({marginLeft : tenPercent},1000 );
    }, 1000 );​
```

**The problem:**

Actually, there is more than one problem with this code.

- It's not working with small window sizes (see fiddle), why?
- When the window is resized after the element flew in, the margin-left is of course not 10% of the new window size. Is there a solution for it? Applying `.css("margin-left","10%");` seems a bit redundant. Maybe something with `resize();`?

*I would really appreciate any form of help!*

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not positioning the element absolutely:

```
#div1 {
    left: -20%;
    position: absolute
}

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div1').animate({left : 0},1000 );
}, 1000 );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LdfZw/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems way to complicated for this little effect.
You may want to use JQueryUI Slide-Effect http://jsfiddle.net/nvEyc/

Otherwise without JQuery UI i'd do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uGXb3/

works with window resize since % values are used.

basically its:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $ ('#div1').animate({marginLeft : "10%"},1000 );
    }, 1000 );​
```

and

```
#div1 {
    margin-left:-100%;
}​
```

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in the answer itself**. External links can rot. More (applies to answers, too): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew jQuery UI `slide`, but for that page I don't want to load another script.